# Save XML from SimpleXMLElement failed to open stream error

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

The XML file and the folder on the server where the file is kept are world read write in a Windows Vista, IIS 7 environment. Calling the asXML function returns this warning and the file isn't updated.

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::asXML(communities.xml) simpleelement.asxml failed to open stream: permission denied in c:\path\make_update.php.
```

The file make_update.php updates nodes in the XML.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function make_update( $nodeid, $name, $top, $left, $width, $height ) {

$nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('communities.xml', null, true);

$returnArray = $nodes->xpath("//COMMUNITY[@ID='$nodeid']");  
$node = $returnArray[0]; 
$node->TOP = $top;

$nodes->asXML('communities.xml');

return $node->TOP;
}

echo make_update(trim($_REQUEST['nodeid']),trim($_REQUEST['name']),trim($_REQUEST['top']),trim($_REQUEST['left']),trim($_REQUEST['width']),trim($_REQUEST['height']));

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to set permission on the folder containing the XML file in addition to the file to be read write. Did so by owner, system, user, iisuser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I'm running IIS 7 with php
I have 'Failed to open stram error' whith SimpleXMLElement::asXML.

I resolved the issue by granting write access to 'everyone'.
this solution only for internal wesites because it's risky.

user823527's solution didn't wok for me.

UPDATE: I fixed the issue by granting write acces to 'IUSR' and 'IIS_USRS'

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed the issue by granting write acces to 'IUSR' and 'IIS_USRS'.